# Getting NONE in the last row of dataframe when using pd.read_sql_query

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to create a db using sqlite3. i created methods to read write delete and show table. however in order to view table in proper format on Command line, i decided to use pandas (pd.read_sql_query). However, when i do that i get None in the last row of the first column.

I tried writing the table to a csv and there was no none value there.

```
def show_table():
    df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM ticket_info", SQLITEDB.conn, index_col='resource_id')
    print(df)
    df.to_csv('hahaha.csv')

def fetch_from_db(query):
    df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM ticket_info WHERE {}'.format(query), SQLITEDB.conn, index_col='resource_id')
    print(df)
```

here's the output as a picture.[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBxzb.png)
Everything is correct but the last None value, where is it coming from? and how do i gt rid of it?

Comment: What is in *query* that you format into SQL string?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `query` as a variable. You might have a query that doesn't return any data from you table.